# Build using expo eas and got gitCommitMessage error

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

When I start build using eas android app-bundle I'm receiving this message:

```
Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more
  ValidationError: "gitCommitMessage" is not allowed to be empty
```

**eas.json**

```
{
    "build": {
        "preview": {
            "android": {
                "buildType": "app-bundle",
                "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease",
                "developmentClient": false,
                "withoutCredentials": true
            }
        },
        "production": {}
    }
}
```

I don't know what happens

Answer (score 1):

Such error message could be caused by a few things that I can think of.

1. The last commit on one or more of the files you made to the branch you are checked out to when running `eas build` has an empty message

If this is the case the solution would be to add a new commit (it could be an empty one, but with a message). Here is an example of how to do that:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Place commit message here"
```

2. Alternatively, but less likely, you may be running the `eas build` command with an empty string after a message flag "-m". Example:

   eas build -p all -m

If this is the case, either remove the "-m" flag, or add a message to your build similarly to the above `eas build -p all -m YOUR_COMMENT`

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."